# import class from file gives unexpedted string error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a very simple server script for a game using sockets.

I basically have a server.js that uses express and socket.io to accept a connection and serve whatever is in public folder.

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
let server = app.listen(3000);
let socket = require("socket.io");
let io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on("connection", newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {
    console.log("New connection: " + socket.id);
}
```

This is a basic script that accepts connections from a client and just prints when a client has connected.

I already did a `npm init`, installed express and socket.io and I run it using `npm start` and it works correctly.

Now, I have build a class Game in a file Game.js and when a client connects I just want to instantiate the game.

Something like:

```
function newConnection(socket) {
    console.log("New connection: " + socket.id);
    let game = new Game();
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to import Game.

I tried using import, but apparently I'm not using the right syntax:

```
import "game.js"

import "game.js"
       ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

I just want inside my server.js to use a class that I implemented in a file that is in the same folder. How can I do this?

Comment: If you are running recent version of node, that supports import statements look at the correct syntax here: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_specifiers . Otherwise fallback to `require` statement.

Answer (score 0):

When using node, you don't use the "import" keyword but rather "require" (Like you already did with express and socket.io in your server.js).

This would look something like:

```
let game = require("game.js");
```

Don't forget to export the needed functions inside your game.js.

```
exports.newConnection = function(socket) {
    console.log("New connection: " + socket.id);
    let game = new Game();
}
```

This way, you can call your newConnection function from inside the server.js by typing:

```
io.sockets.on("connection", game.newConnection);
```

If you only need one function from inside a class, you can also just "require" a single function by explicitly stating this function, like:

```
let gameconnection = require("game.js").newConnection;
```

and then calling it with:

```
io.sockets.on("connection", gameconnection);
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I saw I have to add a `./` before the file name to tell node to search the file in the same folder.